# Remove object located within specified start and end time

Tags: java, intervals

I'm writing a code that cut subtitle if it is within specified interval

I have arraylist that stores all subtitles and save it in global variable

```
ArrayList<Subtitle> subs ;
```

this is the subtitle class

```
class Subtitle{

    Time startTime;
    Time endTime;
    String text;

  }
```

and this is the time class which I used
it stores the time as this format -> hh:mm:ss,ms

```
class Time{

    int hh;
    int mm;
    int ss;
    int ms;
}
```

this is my cut method

```
    public void cut(Time startTime, Time endTime) {

            for (Iterator<Subtitle> iterator = subs.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {

    Subtitle subtitle = iterator.next();

                Time subtitleStartTime = subtitle.getStartTime();
                Time subtitleEndTime = subtitle.getEndTime();

                if (subtitleStartTime.getHH() >= startTime.getHH() && 
subtitleStartTime.getMM() >= startTime.getMM()
                        && subtitleStartTime.getSS() >= startTime.getSS() 
&& subtitleStartTime.getMS() >= startTime.getMS()
                        && subtitleEndTime.getHH() <= endTime.getHH() &&
 subtitleEndTime.getMM() <= endTime.getMM()
                        && subtitleEndTime.getSS() <= endTime.getSS() &&
 subtitleEndTime.getMS() <= endTime.getMS()) {


            iterator.remove();

                }
            }
        }
```

but it never enter the if statement.
will someone help me how to do it without using JAVA libraries.

Comment: Have your `Time` class implement `Comparable<Time>` and then provide an appropriate `compareTo()` method.  You should also implement `equals()` and `hashCode()` for completeness.

Comment: @JimGarrison I used Comparable<Object> before but just to compare one variable, how can I compare 4 variables ? thanks for ur response

Comment: YOU write the `compareTo()` method to compare whatever you want.

Comment: @JimGarrison can you show me algorithm so I can understand please, thank you in advance.